# Differences between a controller class and an ordinary class in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I believe the controller is tied to the user session. So if a user has been directed to an action lets say `mycontroller#index`, followed by the user continuing on to some other action like `show`, the data from `index` is lost. I'm not sure if this is how it works. But I'm confused about controllers and regular ruby classes. I mean, controllers are also classes arent they? Just like any other ruby class.. What are the main differences to keep in mind? I already know of one if I'm not mistaken, and that is, you can't share data between methods as easily in controllers as you can in regular ruby classes. Could someone explain some other differences or demystify my noob like questions related to this topic? thank you in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although controllers are Ruby classes, they do not share data between actions by default. This is because you normally use an instance variables (such as `@user`) in each method or action. These variables only exist for one instance of the controller, and a new instance is made for each request. This means that once one request is over, the next request will not have any of the same instance variables. Usually this is a good thing, since you typically do not want your users to not share their data.

If you want a persistent way of sharing information between actions but having the value be the same for every user, you can use class variables (such as `@@user`).

Another way of sharing information between actions that is more unique per user would be using cookies. Essentially, you can set cookies that are only for one session, are permanent, or are "signed". Signing is to make sure that the user cannot change the value of the cookie. Here are the different types of cookie you can set and read from:

```
cookies[:foo]
cookies.signed[:foo]
cookies.permanent[:foo]
cookies.permanent.signed[:foo]
```

More information about cookies can be found in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Rails also has the [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session), which can be set to use different methods of storage and is very flexible.

Comment: Thanks so much for that explanation. How about i have a regular old ruby class that would parse my csv file and store the records in a hash. Could that hash be used in my controller methods? How would i structure that? Would that cause issues from user session to session? Thank you!

Comment: @TazMan Sure, you can use that hash in your controller. What are you trying to do with the csv hash? The setup all depends on what you are trying to use it for.

Comment: I'll be presenting that csv data to an index page until user moves to another page. The data should go poof once user leaves page and comes back

Comment: @TazMan I'm not sure the best way to do this, but if you want a user to only see information once, you will need to store a value somewhere that can tell you whether each user has seen the information or not. If you just use a class variable to store an array of users who have seen the information already, then it will be reset when you restart the Rails server unless you store the array in a database. Alternatively, you could set a cookie for every user stating that they have seen the information, but the user would then have the power to delete that cookie and see the information again.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: The user variables have to come from user side (cookies) and not server otherwise each user will be just viewing one big pot of data mix.

This is something which stumped me too when I began with rails. I tried to make some `attr_accessor`s and the app went completely haywire. So let's see why this is so.

You app is potentially used by many people at the same time. i.e. multiple persons accessing same piece of code. Therefore, things such as instance variable don't(shouldn't) be used to share data between actions(methods) since there is no knowing who gets what.

Instead, we use database and sessions to link a user to a sandbox of sorts where a set of variables correspond only to him. For any other user, another set of same variables occur in session. This way, mutual exclusion can be maintained between users.